# Searching multiple sites or databases at once

Tags: database, search, web-crawler

My issue is that at my current job, we have to go to 7 different sites, depending on the carrier, to find out a part number through a model number. Each site allows you to search a database with a model number and if it is found it you can see the part number for it. This really helps us out, but I'm looking for a way to make it more convienient for us. Each site requires a login. How can I search all the sites, sites databases at once or how can I make something, webpage or program, that has a tab for each site and when clicked it takes me right to the search feature of the site. Any suggestions are appreciated. I really need to be pointed in the right direction. I almost forgot, if you know a site or program that does this for hvac part or appliances please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to integrate directly with each site most likely, so you're stuck having to login to each and do your work.

But there is some hope!

Check out Selenium (http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) for automating web tasks. For example, you should be able to "record" yourself logging in and clicking to a page - and then in the future you just run a script and Selenium will do it for you. Should save a few steps.

You'd still need a tab open per site, but it should help.